# Is there are way to reuse a function with different values in a code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters

I am wondering if there is a way to repeat a function with different values in the code

I've asked my teacher, searched online, asked some peers and none have the answer

```
while cashChoice > 0:
    cash1 = 200 + int(offer1)*50
    cashorBox = input("Would you like the money or the box? You have been offered $" + str(cash1) + ". If you want money, press [m], if you want the box, press [b]")
    if cashorBox == "m":
        print("Congratulations, you get " + str(cash1) + "! The prize you could've won from the box was " + str(userBox) + ". See you!")
        sys.exit
    elif cashorBox == "b":
        print("Ok... you will be offered another cash amount.")
        cashChoice -= cashChoice
    if cashChoice == 0:
        print("Great! You may have the box. It contains " + str(userBox) + "! Farewell :)")
        sys.exit
    else:
        continue
```

I want it to repeat but with different values of "cash1" as in "cash2"

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly? I don't even see `cash2` defined in your code.

Comment: Do you mean [function parameters](https://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html#function-parameters)?

Comment: Why can't you just define a function with cash1 and cash2 as input?

Comment: Are you trying to ask about **arrays** (called `list` in Python)?  So you can have “variables” like `cash[1]`, `cash[2]`, `cash[3]`, …?

Comment: Yes @DavisHerring thats kinda what im trying to do

Comment: @Anonymous: So did the accepted answer address your problem or not?

Comment: @DavisHerring yes thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple answer for this, and it will be very important to know later on if you wish to become proficient in Python. I don't know exactly how you are wanting to implement this, but you can do it like so:

```
def yourFunction (cash1Param):
    while cashChoice > 0:
        cash1 = cash1Param
        cashorBox = input("Would you like the money or the box? You have been offered $" + str(cash1) + ". If you want money, press [m], if you want the box, press [b]")
        if cashorBox == "m":
            print("Congratulations, you get " + str(cash1) + "! The prize you could've won from the box was " + str(userBox) + ". See you!")
            sys.exit
        elif cashorBox == "b":
            print("Ok... you will be offered another cash amount.")
            cashChoice -= cashChoice
        if cashChoice == 0:
            print("Great! You may have the box. It contains " + str(userBox) + "! Farewell :)")
            sys.exit
        else:
            continue
```

Then, when you call the function, you can enter any value for cash1Param, such as:

```
yourFunction(5)
```

or

```
yourFunction(678678967)
```

You don't even need to use cash1 for everything. You could just replace all of the times you have used it with cash1Param to directly use the parameter.

These are called function parameters. Here is a relevant link for learning them: https://www.protechtraining.com/content/python_fundamentals_tutorial-functions

If you have any further questions, don't be afraid to ask.

Comment: @DavisHerring Ah, thanks my man. Embarrassing that I missed that lol. Still new to the Stackoverflow formatting interface.

Comment: OK, now it gets `UnboundLocalError`.  More importantly, does that `while` accomplish what the questioner wants (the acceptance notwithstanding)?  Or is the goal to change from “cash1” to “cash2” over different iterations of *that* loop?

Comment: @DavisHerring 1/2 I am assuming the questioner only posted a snippet of his code and that cashChoice was defined earlier on in the hypothetical function, which explains the `UnboundLocalError`. I answered the question relative to how I interpreted it, which, admittedly, is not the best idea, as some further elaboration of this question may have been needed. While an accepted answer may not be completely indicative of me having answered what the questioner initially actually wanted, I guess we both can't know completely until he explains himself more in the comments. You are right. A list would

Comment: @DavisHerring 2/2 be the answer if he is wanting different values within the same loop.